# Sending message to iframe from Chrome extension content script is not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my chrome extension, I'm loading an iframe when a user right clicks on a media and clicks on a context menu item. In the iframe, I render a HTML file which shows the details about the media clicked on.

To do this, I'm capturing the context menu item click in the background page and sending it to the current active tab.

```js
// A generic onclick callback function.
function onClick(info) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
        ...info,
        type: "show-modal-window"});  
    });
}

// Registers a callback for when a context menu item is clicked
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClick);
```

I capture this message in the content script and render an iframe as follows. Also, I'm sending the event data to iframe from the content script via `postMessage`.

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.type === "show-modal-window") {
      // Inject the modal window HTML file into the current web page.
      var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("./modal.html");
      iframe.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log("msg sent")
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message,'*') ;
      })
      // some iframe styles
      iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
});
```

The modal.html and modal.js files are as follows.

**modal.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Modal Window</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="modal-window">
    <p>File name: <span id="fileName"></span></p>
  </div>
  <script src="modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**modal.js**

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.type === "show-modal-window") {
        console.log("mmm")
        console.log(event.data)
        document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = event.data.linkUrl;
    }
})
```

The problem I'm facing here is that **the `fileName` element is never populated with the `linkUrl`** nor the console.logs inside modal.js event listeners are fired. It seems like the message never reaches the iframe. How can I make this work? All helpful suggestions are appreciated.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "<omitted_for_privacy>",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "<omitted_for_privacy>",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "<omitted_for_privacy>",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "logo.png",
        "32": "logo.png",
        "48": "logo.png",
        "128": "logo.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["*://*/*"],
          "js": ["content_script.js","modal.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["modal.html","modal.js"],
            "matches": ["*://*/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There's no DOMContentLoaded for iframe object, it's just `load`. Tip: use the second parameter (tab) of [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#event-onClicked) instead of chrome.tabs.query.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wOxxOm. That was exactly the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks generally correct with a few adjustments needed to make it work. Let's work through it step by step.

Event Type Check:
In your modal.js, you are checking for the event.type which doesn't exist on the message event. Instead, you should be checking the type within event.data.

```
if (event.data.type === "show-modal-window")
```

Listening to the Right Origin:
For security reasons, it's a good practice to specify the origin in the postMessage method and also verify the origin when receiving a message. Using "*" as the target origin in postMessage sends the message to any origin. This can be a security vulnerability. It's best to be specific.
With the extension's origin:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, chrome.runtime.getURL(''));
```

On the receiving side (modal.js), check the origin to ensure it's from your extension:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.origin !== chrome.runtime.getURL('')) {
        return;  // not from our extension, ignore
    }
    if (event.data.type === "show-modal-window") {
        document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = event.data.linkUrl;
    }
});
```

in Manifest V3, the "web_accessible_resources" doesn't have a "matches" property like this. If you intended to allow the iframe to access any page, you'll need to modify this.

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "modal.html",
    "modal.js"
  ],
```